# <br /> tags are getting removed while pasting in nicedit textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicedit

I am calling an instance of nicedit:

```
var st = new nicEditor({
  maxHeight: 220,
  texteditor: <%=raw @editor_trs.to_json%>
}).panelInstance('template_body');
```

Once this is done, I am doing copy paste of some string having `<br />` tags. But while pasting these tags are removed.

Need help on preventing the tags while copy paste.

Comment: It's most likely down to the settings of the editor that they are stripped. Check their documentation

Comment: Never heard of nicedit. But maybe the <pre> tag can help you.

Comment: This is resolved. This was getting removed because it was sending text values, not the HTML values. If the value is sent as HTML, then this is working fine and is accepting the **`<br />`** tags.